# Installing both windows 10 and ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

can i install both windows 10 and ubuntu in my 4GB Ram Laptop? 
i want to give it a try but i fear that windows 10 might not be able to run smoothly after the process.. 
what are the requirements and under what circumstances can the two operating systems smoothly run?

please help

Comment: "Under the same partition?" No. Each operating system must have it's own partition and file system.

Comment: Hi! I think you mean same "hard drive" and, yes, you can check here :https://askubuntu.com/a/1079981/307184 So, just so we're sure you understand. Ubutnu will be in the same hard drive as windows, you'll be able to choose which one you want to boot when you start your computer. the two systems will not share the same space. Windows will have a space on the hard drive (in NTFS formatting) just for itself and ubuntu will be in a space on the hard drive (in ext4 formatting) just for **it**self. however ubuntu will be able to consult and edit the NTFS partition because ubuntu is able to do that.

Comment: Is system UEFI or BIOS. Microsoft required vendors to install Windows 10 in UEFI mode since Windows 8 in 2012, so most hardware is UEFI. And then you need to install both systems in same boot mode, both UEFI or both BIOS. And how you boot install media UEFI or BIOS for both Ubuntu & Windows is then how it installs.